# Closing hazelcast client connection

Tags: hazelcast

I just started using hazelcast [3.3.1]. Following the hazelcast application and client tutorial, I created a hazelcast application instance and a client (using eclipse IDE).

From the client, I am able to add objects to the map and get them successfully. However, I see the following warnings on instance's console, they seem to warn about the client disconnects. Is this a normal behavior for every client get/put?

Is there a proper way of disconnecting the client connection to the instance before exiting the client program?

HazelcastInstance logs

```
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: Connection [Address[x.x.x.x]:58266] lost. Reason: java.io.IOException[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: Connection [Address[127.0.0.1]:58263] lost. Reason: java.io.IOException[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.ReadHandler WARNING: hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[x.x.x.x]:58266, Cause:java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.ReadHandler WARNING: hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:58263, Cause:java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hazelCastInstance.shutdown(); is the proper way of closing the hazelcast instance...

Comment: that is correct; a client also is a hazelcastinstance and can be shutdown using the shutdown method.

Comment: If you just want to clear the contents of the map, then use the following, hazelcastInstance.get(mapName).clear();